# Access a file outside of root/htdocs on windows in PHP

Tags: php, windows, xampp

How can i access a file outside of htdocs folder on windows?
I have a config file outside of my root (htdocs) folder, in which i want to save off the configuration for my database connection, but when i call it, it says no file found.

i am cureently in the following directory: 
xampp\htdocs\includes

and my config file is in:
\xampp\inc

i tried to echo the path, but i didn't get any output

```
echo realpath('../..inc/config.php') . PHP_EOL;

if (!file_exists('../../inc/config.php')) {
          throw new Exception("No config file found!");
        }
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the first path or did you miscopy?

Comment: At what stage does it say file not found? Is it at the stage where you try to `echo` the `realpath()` or does it get to throw the Exception?

Comment: recheck the folder level. your code works fine for mentioned scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it to work with

```php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/inc/config.php'
```